# Apache Http Client execute request without sending the enclosing entity

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-5.x

I do have the following scenario:

1) The Client sends a HTTP request with an enclosing entity to a Server, via a socket.

2) The Server uploads the enclosing entity to another location, let's call it Storage.

I am required to implement only the Server.

So far, I was able to implement it using [Apache HTTP Components](https://hc.apache.org/index.html) library using something like:

```
// The request from the client
org.apache.http.HttpRequest request = ...;

// The org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity will 
// read bytes from the socket and write to the Storage
HttpEntity entity = new InputStreamEntity(...)

BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest requestToStorage = new ......
requestToStorage.setEntity(entity);

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = ...

CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(target, requestToStorage );
```

So far so good. Problem is, the Storage server requires authentication. When the Server makes the first request (via Apache Http Client API), the Storage responds with 407 Authentication Required. The Apache Http Client makes the initial handshake then **resends the request**, but now there is no entity since it has already been consumed for the first request.

One solution is to cache the entity from the Client, but it can be very big, over 1 GB.

**Question** Is there a better solution, like pre-sending only the request's headers?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `expect-continue` handshake.

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(
                RequestConfig.custom()
                        .setExpectContinueEnabled(true)
                        .build())
        .build();
```

Comment: I was considering this, but what if the server responds with `417 Expectation Failed`? This case I'm forced to repeat the request and my problem is back.

Comment: `You can not have your pie and eat it too`. If the server requires authentication and refuses `expect-continue` handshake you might as well fail the request and return `413` to the client with or without `Retry- After` header depending on whether or not you want the client to retry the request later.